# Where can I learn how to program an NXT using C#?

Tags: programming

I've been toying around with my NXT 2.0 set for a few years now and I would like to learn how to program it using C# language. I have no experience in coding and I am definitely not a computer geek. Are there any tutorials that can give me a headstart in this thing?

Comment: If you have no experience in coding, why are you set on programming the NXT in C#? There are other options, such as using [LeJOS NXJ](http://www.lejos.org/nxj.php) which helps you program the NXT using Java, arguably the language C# was largely modeled after .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start here for example: [LEGO MINDSTORMS NXT Tutorials Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb870550.aspx)

For a generic C# introduction see here: [C# Tutorials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436(v=vs.71).aspx) or [The complete C# Tutorial](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/) or [C# Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/) or just do a Google search for "C# tutorial".

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, i really appreciate that .

Comment: You are welcome! If any answer proved useful to you, you can upvote it with the upward pointing arrow on the left side. Or if you think an answer is the correct one for your problem, you can also mark it with the check mark as accepted, signaling the future readers which solution works.